# obtain the contract of a token through the address of a holder

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transactions, account, token

I am currently learning the basics of programming in solana using the different json functions and I have a question

Is there a function that gives you the contract of a token having only the address of a holder?

I have tried with functions like

GetToken,
GetTransactionList

and none of them worked

The most I have achieved is obtaining the Raydium liquidity pool contract.
and an address called:
associated token account program, which I don't even know what exactly is

Are there functions that I don't know about that will give me what I want? I would greatly appreciate the help thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every token on Solana is currently deployed with one of two different programs:

- Token Program: `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`
- Token-2022/Token Extensions program: `TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb`

What you're asking for is "how can I find the mint address of a token given a specific token account?"

Given a token account `3JpjbbqkGQEwedw7ZHcV3E2cxWrTAbuJeiWiTXW7USTq`, you can find the mint by querying the account:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getAccountInfo",
    "params": [
        "3JpjbbqkGQEwedw7ZHcV3E2cxWrTAbuJeiWiTXW7USTq",
        {
            "encoding": "jsonParsed"
        }
    ]
}'
```

Response:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "context": {
            "apiVersion": "1.17.21",
            "slot": 254055034
        },
        "value": {
            "data": {
                "parsed": {
                    "info": {
                        "isNative": false,
                        "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
                        "owner": "NjordRPSzFs8XQUKMjGrhPcmGo9yfC9HP3VHmh8xZpZ",
                        "state": "initialized",
                        "tokenAmount": {
                            "amount": "212674332017",
                            "decimals": 6,
                            "uiAmount": 212674.332017,
                            "uiAmountString": "212674.332017"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "account"
                },
                "program": "spl-token",
                "space": 165
            },
            "executable": false,
            "lamports": 2039280,
            "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
            "space": 165
        }
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

You can see from this `getAccountInfo` RPC API call, the mint is `EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v`. Doing a lookup on the mint address, you'll find it is USDC.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for.

Let's say I have this wallet 8UMwVssuymUiZ7EpMjFpyVew3ddReri2CjPSDJaNhW4g that recently made a swap in raydium for JUP, is there a way to get the contract to buy JUP through that wallet?

In the tests that I am doing I get all kinds of contracts and addresses but not the contract to buy the token and I think that either I have to use other functions or there is something that I am missing or probably both haha